# Android gmaps api v2 blank screen with zoom button

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I want to use google maps android api v2.
By manual 
[this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) and 
[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). And get only white screen with zoom buttons and dont have errors in LogCat, except

```
E/Google Maps Android API( 1157): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
```

I have a android api key, I activate the Google Maps Android API v2 in google console. (and google maps api v2 too),I write all permission on manifest file, I include a google-play-services_lib to my project, and android-support-v4.jar too.

Use Mac, ADT

UPDATE: this err only on emulator. how to fix it?

Comment: the message says your device must support open gl es 2.0 and above. test it on a device that supports the same. testing it on emulator?

Comment: Yes.
Target: google api 17

Comment: try to start on htc with 4.0.4 - no err, and show map. How fix it on emulator?

Comment: you can't fix it on emulator. BCOZ, Emulator is't support OPEN GL.

Comment: thanks a lot. 3 day.. 3 long day..